# creating jquery custom object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In asp I have a function as:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> updateComment(int id, Comment comment)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

To send data to this function I have created an ojbect as (I am working with knockout.js):

```
var com =  {
                id: self.id,
                description: self.description,
                postedBy: self.postedById,
                time: new Date($.now()),
                adId: self.adId,
            };
```

And in ajax request I am sending data as:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/api/Comment/updateComment',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: com.id, comment: com },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("done");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

But request does not goes to above asp.net function. I got error in browser console window `404 (Not Found)` . Error is because it is not receiving `comment` object as it was expecting. I changed ajax request method to get to see url and url is below.
[image]

Is there something wrong with my defined `com` function? Why its not working?

**Update**:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> updateComment()
{
    //some stuff
}
```

I changed the function as above and its working fine. So it is confirmed that is some problem with `com` object. Function is not receiving object as it was expecting.

**Update 2**:

Now I changed function parameters to:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> updateComment(Comment comment)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

and send data as:

```
data: ko.toJSON(com),
```

and its again working fine!

Comment: You have a typo in y our success callback function. Remove the **'**

Comment: yeah that was a typing mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: write the attribute `[HttpPost]` above the method name.

Comment: ok! It does not work. still getting error `404 (Not Found)`

Comment: 404 is Page Not Found Error. Make sure you are using correct `URL`

Comment: just a thought; to call a ASP method from jquery, should't it be a web method?

Comment: `URL` is correct. All other functions are working fine. I think the error is because of the `com` object. The url in picture does not seem awkward??

Comment: @IrfanWattoo is ASP method, a web method? do u happen to know about CORS?

Comment: this is a webapi method as my controller is extended by `apiController`

Comment: can u show us `Comment` class to

Answer (score 1):

error code is `405:Method not allowed` i guess this is something like, your ajax is `type:"Post"` request but your backend is expecting some `GET` requests.

---

Another suggestion is that you can send a stringified object with this:

```
data : '{ "id":"' + com.id + '", "comment":"' + com + '"}',
```

Comment: Method is receiving `POST` request. And I am also sending `POST` request. the picture is of `GET` request which I just take to check url how object is being sent. `405:Method not allowed` is because it is receiving `POST` request but I am sending `GET` ONLY this time

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look if it helps.

Comment: 405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form. you can check more about it from here: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: `data : JSON.stringify({ id: com.id, comment: com }),` try with it once.

Comment: sorry. I think you had misunderstood the question. Actually I am getting `404 (Not Found)` not found error. The picture is posted just to show url using GET request

Comment: @IrfanWattoo can you please post a working url, may be you would take a look @ this `/` before `api`

Comment: still not working. `POST http://localhost:59322/api/Comment/updateComment 404 (Not Found)` error

Comment: As mentioned in question update. When I remove function parameters then its working fine. I think there is no issue with url. Only issue is with parameters.

Comment: Okay! then i guess you should try creating a json string and try sending that.

Comment: try with this json string = `data : '{ "id":"' + com.id + '", "comment":"' + com + '"}',`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax post with `two` parameters `class object` and `other type` you need to create other obj like below:

**Note:** Make sure that all properties of com object are same like your Comment class.

```
var com =  {
            id: self.id,
            description: self.description,
            postedBy: self.postedById,
            time: new Date($.now()),
            adId: self.adId,
        };

var obj = {};
obj.id = com.id;
obj.comment = com;
```

And pass data using `JSON.Stringy(obj)` like below:

```
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
```

I had tested the code it is working check below screen shot:

[image]

Comment: not working!! `404 (Not Found)` I have updated question. Please take a look.

Comment: change your parameter int type to string and create obj like i shown above sequence and check once.

Comment: thank you but I have wasted much time on it. I found a worst solution. I just removed id parameter.